# Is it possible to create a VHDL user-defined attribute on a type that calls a function taking an instance of the type as an argument?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, quartus

I've been expanding my VHDL knowledge and have been playing around with user-defined attributes. I want to be able to define an attribute "max" that returns the largest element of an array and applies to all instances of an array type. For example `somearray'max` calls a function maximum with "somearray" as the argument. Similar in behavior to the pre-defined attribute `somearray'length` An example would be:

```
type my_array is array (natural range <>) of integer range 0 to 255;

function maximum(a : my_array) return integer;

attribute max : integer;
attribute max of my_array : type is maximum(???); -- is there a way to make the argument generic?

signal data : my_array;
largest_element <= data'max;
```

So far, I've only been able to attach the attribute to a specific object, such as:

```
signal data : my_array;

attribute max : integer;
attribute max of data : signal is maximum(data);
```

Is it possible to make it generic for a specific type (like the pre-defined attributes), or is this a limitation of VHDL?

Sure, I could just do this:

```
largest_element <= maximum(data);
```

But, as I stated it's a learning exercise.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.7 Attribute declarations "User-defined attributes are constants of arbitrary type." The term generic has a specific connotation in the standard (6.5.2 Interface object declarations, 6.5.6.2 Generic clauses). Additionally an attribute specification must occur within the declarative part containing the declaration of the named entity being decorated (7.2 Attribute specification). A user defined attribute is a value that decorates something that is named (declared explicitly or implicitly). Predefined attributes are basic operations (5. Types, 5.1).

Comment: It's an intentional limitation. VHDL is a formal notation intended for formal verification. That precludes extensible syntax and semantics in the face of another goal - portability.

Comment: Short answer: No. And some tools dont always play nice with user defined attributes (though many have predifned attributes that cause the tools to do specific things). For this kind of operation, functions are the answer. All discrete and integer types have MAXIMUM and MINIMUM functions defined implicity, so with generic functions in VHDL2008 it should be fairly straight forward to define a max/min functions for all arrays of an integer or discrete type.

Comment: @Tricky thanks. Yes, min/max functions are trivial (my current code simply calls a function). This was just an exercise to learn about the limitations of user-defined attributes. I understand VHDL well enough. At the moment I'm exploring some of the more esoteric bits (groups are next)

Comment: Per first comment, " constants of arbitrary type" is key. So, when the attribute is declared, can `maximum(???)` be evaluated to a constant value? In your second case, `maximum(data)` can. If you subtyped `my_array` to a fixed size `subtype colour is my_array(1 to 3);` then I would expect `attribute max of my_colour : signal is maximum(colour);` to work. Caveat : not tested.